# How to align all the definitions in a symbol list (Word 2010)

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to align all of the definitions in a symbol list in word 2010.
Now they all look like this

[image]

Anyone knows how to do this? I wanna align the definitions as well.

Comment: There is almost certainly a separate SE group for doing this.  There may be a better / alternative way to do this but put them in a two column table but do not put borders around the cells.  Then align all text in the table to the left side of the cells.  It should look exactly how you want.

Comment: I think you misread the site name: *World*, not *Word*.

Comment: lets use sharelatex

Comment: wordbuilding :D

Comment: I probably shouldn't answer this here but (a) use a fixed-width font such as Courier New  and (b) get rid of all those messed-up spaces and use the Tab key instead.